# Left join big boolean matrices in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two matrices with boolean columns (flags):

- `process_state` - tracks set of attributes for units in process
- `configuration` - defines process state class using combination of attributes

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd838/1)

Simple example:

```
process_state
a   b   c
t   t   t
t   f   t
f   f   t

configuration
a   b   c,   process_state_class
t   t   t    classa
f   f   f    classb
f   f   NULL classc
```

Now I need to left join configuration to process state in order to figure out to what configuration (process state class) belongs to process state (if any). `NULL` in configuration indicates that  this column can contain any value (`true, false`) in process state. There are never `NULLL` values in process state table.

I have:

```
   select
     *
   from
     process_state ps
     left join configuration c on (
            ((ps.a = c.a) or c.a is null)
        and ((ps.b = c.b) or c.b is null)
        and ((ps.c = c.c) or c.c is null)
     )
```

I have a lot of configurations and a lot of columns (20) and also it is quite often that one process state belongs to more than one configuration. This makes the whole query slow.

Is there a different SQL way how to write such query? And because I am owner of these tables, is there a different way how to approach this problem from beginning? I thought I will have only 0/1 strings in both tables like:

```
 process_state
 abc
 111
 101
 001
```

and then use simple left join. Unfortunately, this does not for work configurations with some `NULL`.

More realistic data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/268f9/4)

This is the explain plan I get for sample data with 100000 rows in process state and 300 rows in configuration and 15 boolean attributes:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..8863403.33 rows=5829 width=30) (actual time=0.145..8673.960 rows=14318 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (((ps.a = c.a) OR (c.a IS NULL)) AND ((ps.b = c.b) OR (c.b IS NULL)) AND ((ps.c = c.c) OR (c.c IS NULL)) AND ((ps.d = c.d) OR (c.d IS NULL)) AND ((ps.e = c.e) OR (c.e IS NULL)) AND ((ps.f = c.f) OR (c.f IS NULL)) AND ((ps.g = c.g) OR (c.g IS NULL)) AND ((ps.h = c.h) OR (c.h IS NULL)) AND ((ps.i = c.i) OR (c.i IS NULL)) AND ((ps.j = c.j) OR (c.j IS NULL)) AND ((ps.k = c.k) OR (c.k IS NULL)) AND ((ps.l = c.l) OR (c.l IS NULL)) AND ((ps.m = c.m) OR (c.m IS NULL)) AND ((ps.n = c.n) OR (c.n IS NULL)) AND ((ps.o = c.o) OR (c.o IS NULL)))
  ->  Seq Scan on process_state ps  (cost=0.00..1520.21 rows=97921 width=15) (actual time=0.007..11.835 rows=100000 loops=1)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..37.15 rows=1810 width=15) (actual time=0.000..0.017 rows=300 loops=100000)
        ->  Seq Scan on configuration c  (cost=0.00..28.10 rows=1810 width=15) (actual time=0.004..0.036 rows=300 loops=1)
Total runtime: 8674.763 ms
```

I tried to collapse both tables into single column and replaced `NULL` in configuration with `.`. Now I can use single condition regexp join:

```
select
  *
from
  process_state ps
  left join configuration c on (ps.process_state ~~ c.configuration)
```

Still, no significant improvement when compared to explain plan above:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..451546.75 rows=150000 width=32) (actual time=154.127..6971.697 rows=22 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (ps.process_state ~~ c.configuration)
  ->  Seq Scan on process_state2 ps  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.006..12.700 rows=100000 loops=1)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6.50 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.020 rows=300 loops=100000)
        ->  Seq Scan on configuration2 c  (cost=0.00..5.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.036 rows=300 loops=1)
Total runtime: 6971.721 ms
```

I also tried replacing `NULL` with `_` and use `like` operator - no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but I'm not sure it will be any faster:

```
select
 *
from
 process_state ps
 left join configuration c 
         on ps.a = coalesce(c.a, ps.a)
        and ps.b = coalesce(c.b, ps.b)
        and ps.c = coalesce(c.c, ps.c)
```

Comment: Thank you, works, but not speed improvement at all. Matches almost exactly to explain plan I posted.